# Reboot mobile programmatically

Tags: flutter, native, flutter-method-channel

Hi team i created flutter project and my task is if i press the restart button mobile device need to got restarted but if i press the button it wont works got error in console

> error -> either user 10478 nor current process has android.permission.REBOOT

android code for restart

```
  private void restart() {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        pm.reboot(null);
    }
```

I have added the permission in androidmanifest too, but no luck.

do I need to restart my device?

Comment: Are you sure you dont also need a runtime permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
```

**2**

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void requestRebootPermission() async {
  var status = await Permission.reboot.request();
  if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    print('Permission denied');
    return;
  }
}
```

**3**

```
await requestRebootPermission();
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
pm.reboot(null);
```